# SQL Server - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to declare these values and use execute them to get a specific values of an attribute in a table. However everytime I am time trying to set @test and @columnPeriod it gives me the error *Must declare the scalar variable "@test"* or *Must declare the scalar variable "@columnPeriod"*

```
DECLARE @columnPeriod VARCHAR(MAX), @test INT;
SET @test = 2015;
SET @columnPeriod = 'SELECT Period FROM Courses WHERE year = ' + @test + '';
```

Comment: Why is columnPeriod an int when you are storing a string?  Change @columnPeriod to be varchar or nvarchar.

Comment: Thanks for mentionening it. Just a spelling mistake @JonH

Comment: if you run `SELECT Period FROM Courses WHERE year = '2015';` do you get more than 1 record returned? what about `SELECT distinct Period FROM Courses WHERE year = '2015';`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error.   When I run the code in your question, I get `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT Period FROM Courses WHERE year = ' to data type int.` and that's because you are trying to do string concatenation with the int-type variable `test`.   It is pretty hard for people to help you if you don't post the actual code that produces the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine Strings and INTs

Try

```
SET @columnPeriod = 'SELECT Period FROM Courses WHERE year = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),@test) + ' Limit 1';
```

This will also limit your selection to ensure it is scalar

Comment: I understand that I wrote INT as the variabel type but that was a mistake. I have it as VARCHAR(MAX). However, even I try running `SET @test = 2015;` it gives me the error.

Comment: If both are varchar, change your original post.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @columnPeriod INT, @test varchar(4);
SET @test = '2015';
SET @columnPeriod = SELECT distinct Period FROM Courses WHERE year = ' + @test + '';
```

Assumptions being:

- period only has ONE record with year 2015  if you have more than one but all the same "period" then distinct may be needed.  If you have multiple, you can't do this as the record set returned has more than one row...
- Year is a varchar datatype